# Is there a way to get Mysql to make the unique ID generate with letters and numbers? (or PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is there a way i could make the unique id (primary key) in Mysql generate with numbers and letters to keep the id as short as possible? If I cant do this in Mysql how could i get PHP to generate this? Thanks :)

Comment: Does it have to be the primary key? If you want to form a URL from it, generating a random string in a separate column might be the better option.

Comment: How short do you want the key to be?

Comment: @ypercube as short as possible.

Comment: @user: So, 1 byte, 1 character is OK?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Encoding as [Base 36](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_36) is a good choice for this as it utilises 0-9 A-Z and so is compact.
You can leave mysql using integers and translate between the two [in PHP](http://devlog.info/2008/05/22/encoding-numbers-as-base-36/), or derive a base 36 value from an incrementing id + trigger.

Comment: +1. You can have the id stored as integer and the conversions done in either PHP or MySQL (using `CONV()` function).

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this, unless you're using a MySQL trigger to update on of your fields automatically after an insert. Other option is to handle the unique alphanumeric values with your PHP script:

```
1) insert
2) get insert_id();
3) generate unique alphanumeric string
4) update
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of it in mysql but in PHP you can use uniqid

http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Comment: Drawback of this function is it not respect standard UUID. [UUID on Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)